# How to start CMD screen in a X,Y position in c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to know how can i set the coord of a c++ cmd screen, like to start in the windows 0,0 pixel.

probably is something with the system(""); but i don't know

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that pixel `(0,0)` exists if you have multiple monitorswith different resolutions, e.g. a laptop with an external docking station. Generally at least one corner is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CreateProcess` API, and pass `STARTUPINFO` structure with coordinates in `dwX`,`dwY` fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the process then use a SetWindowPos